# Can't toggle bootstrap dropdown nicely with knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm trying to nest a dropdown inside an element which already has a click event bound to it.

I have disabled bubbling on the dropdown and created a clickhandler to trigger it manually by calling `$(...).dropdown()`

When I try to trigger a dropdown the dropdown box requires two clicks at a minimum before it begins to work.

When you use `$(...).dropdown('toggle')` it works on the first click but after that the functionality is broken.

Here is a JSFiddle that exactly mimics my structure.

## [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fh8Lszav/)

Comment: do you want to open dropdown on first click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this function in your script it's work fine

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
});
```

I update your jsfiddle [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/fh8Lszav/2/)

Comment: Alright so this works, what is happening when you call that function at load time that needs to happen before this works? Does dropdow() bind listeners to the element?